# Why doesn't LaTeXmk output erros and warning in the console output in TeXworks?

Tags: xetex, errors, warnings, latexmk, texworks

I've been using TeXLive in TeXworks for compiling my XeLaTeX documents only recently and coming from online Overleaf, I had to make a switch in explicitly giving the commands for compiling. Luckily, I came across the LaTeXmk package, which goes through most of the compiling and typesetting trouble for me: I have a document with a `bibtex` bibliography and I use the `glossaries` package.

Now I call the LaTeXmk package with the option `-xelatex` and it works like a charm. However, with this option only, the console output in TeXworks no longer displays warnings and errors, such as overfull boxes and undefined references. I tried to fix this by including the option `-file-line-error`, too, but still the console output doesn't show me the usual errors and warnings tab. In the same way, I've tried the following options to no avail:

- `-logfilewarnings`
- `-logfilewarninglist`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
*In response to John Collins's comment.*

I am running Windows 10 Home, version 1909, OS build 18363.720.

I have a `.latexmkrc` file in my document base directory, with the following contents:

```
   add_cus_dep( 'slo', 'sls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
   add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
   add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
   $clean_ext .= "slo sls slg acr acn alg glo gls glg";
   sub makeglossaries {
      my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
      pushd $path;
      my $return = system "makeglossaries", $base_name;
      popd;
      return $return;
   }
```

EDIT 2:
*In response to John Collins' second comment.*

Because I'm running the MWE in the base directory of my actual LaTeX main file, I believe it is also loading the packages of that main file somehow? Anyway, the MWE that I'm running (very minimal):

```latex
\documentclass{tudelft-report}

\begin{document}
Hi

% This should give me an unresolved reference warning.
\ref{nonexistentref}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding console output:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67.
Rule 'xelatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'test.tex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="out"  "test.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-02-25> (./tudelft-report.cls
Document Class: tudelft-report 2013/06/22 v1.0 TU Delft thesis class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-dutch/dutch.ldf
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocbibind/tocbibind.sty

Package tocbibind Note: Using chapter style headings, unless overridden.

) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-xetex.def))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex))))
(out/test.aux)
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(out/test.out) (out/test.out) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 7.

(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/se-ascii-print.def) [1]
(out/test.aux) )
Output written on out/test.xdv (1 page, 1020 bytes).
Transcript written on out/test.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'out/test.xdv'
Rule 'xelatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'out/test.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="out"  "test.tex"'
------------
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-02-25> (./tudelft-report.cls
Document Class: tudelft-report 2013/06/22 v1.0 TU Delft thesis class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-dutch/dutch.ldf
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocbibind/tocbibind.sty

Package tocbibind Note: Using chapter style headings, unless overridden.

) (c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-xetex.def))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex))))
(out/test.aux)
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(out/test.out) (out/test.out) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

LaTeX Warning: Reference `nonexistentref' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.

(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/se-ascii-print.def) [1]
(out/test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
Output written on out/test.xdv (1 page, 1148 bytes).
Transcript written on out/test.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'out/test.xdv'
Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
  Reference `nonexistentref' on page 1 undefined on input line 7
Rule 'xdvipdfmx': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'out/test.xdv'
   Rule(s) that have been run and require run of dependent rule:
      'xelatex' which requires run of 'xdvipdfmx'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xdvipdfmx'
------------
------------
Running 'xdvipdfmx -o "out\test.pdf"  "out\test.xdv"'
------------
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'xdvipdfmx'...
For rule 'xdvipdfmx', running '&do_viewfile(  )' ...
out\test.xdv -> test.pdf
[1]
31207 bytes written
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of (pdf)latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 reference(s)
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

EDIT 3: *a screenshot of the missing tab.*
Below are two screenshots of the console output. Upon typesetting with LaTeXmk, I don't get the tab `Errors, warnings, badboxes`, which I do get when typesetting with XeLaTeX. In my opinion, this overview is useful because it clearly indicates the severity of the message (blue, yellow, red) and offers a clickable reference to the corresponding line.

[image: Upon typesetting with LaTeXmk, only the console output appears.]

[image: Upon typesetting with XeLaTex, an <code>Errors, warnings, badboxes</code> tab appears.]

Comment: I've got latexmk working in my TeXWorks and it does show warnings and errors.  I have few questions to start a diagnosis of your problem.  1.  What OS are you running?  2. Do you have a file named .latexmkrc or latexmkrc in the directory containing your document?  3. If so what are its contents?  If necessary, feel free to contact me at the address in the latexmk documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. See the edited question for my response.

Comment: Thanks for adding the information. I don't see anything in the .latexmkrc file that would cause a problem.  You said TeXworks compiled the document correctly.  Examine the console output for a successful run, not forgetting to scroll up the console window so you can see the beginning.  It will tell you what latexmk did or tried to do, and should provide clues to the problem.  Add the complete the console output into your question. But do this for a very minimal document, to avoid the usual voluminous console output from a large document.  I can probably see the necessary cues.

Comment: Thanks again. I updated my question with an MWE and the console output.

Comment: I don't see any problem.  You say "the console output in TeXworks no longer displays warnings and errors, such as overfull boxes and undefined references". But in the console output there is a warning from xelatex about an undefined reference: "LaTeX Warning: Reference `nonexistentref' on page 1 undefined on input line 7."

Comment: That is my bad. I mean to say that the errors and warnings *tab* TeXworks that usually displays upon compiling disappears when compiling with LaTeXmk. I updated my question again with a screenshot of the tab I'm missing.

Comment: I can reproduce that.  It looks very much like a bug in TeXworks to me.